# Docker - Can't copy file generated inside container out of it

Tags: python, docker

I generate several `.txt` files containing text stats inside a docker container on a server that uses a GPU. After the process is finished after 25h, I can't copy *some* of the generated files out of the container for later usage, while other generated files can be copied.

I might do something wrong while generating the files. Here is the code

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import zlib
import re
import numpy as np
import string
import binascii
from tqdm import tqdm
import stanza

STOP_WORDS = set(["a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by", "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such", "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these", "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"])

stanza.download("en")
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')

for filename in ["dataset.csv"]:
    documents = []
#   ...
#   Code here that generates and stores a document 
#   that can be copied out
#   ...
    i = 0
    token_to_id = {}
    with open(f"{basename}_token_to_id_lemmatized.txt", "w") as f,\
         open(f"{basename}_token_to_docs_lemmatized.txt", "w") as f2,\
         open(f"{basename}_token_to_freqs_lemmatized.txt", "w") as f3:
        # trick to reduce memory-in-use
        for max_range in [(0, 1000), (1000, 2000), (2000, 3000),
                          (3000, 10000), (10000, 20000), (20000, 1000000)]:
            token_to_docs = defaultdict(list)
            for doc_id, doc in enumerate(tqdm(documents)):
                for token, num_token in Counter(doc.split("|")).items():
                    if not token or token not in dictionary:
                        continue
                    if not token_to_id.get(token):
                        token_to_id[token] = i
                        f.write(f"{token}\n")
                        i += 1
                    token_id = token_to_id[token]
                    if max_range[0] <= token_id < max_range[1]:
                        token_to_docs[token_id].append((doc_id, num_token))

            for token_id in tqdm(range(max_range[0], max_range[1])):
                for doc_id, num_token in token_to_docs[token_id]:
                    f2.write(f"{doc_id},")
                    f3.write(f"{num_token},")
                if token_to_docs[token_id]:
                    f2.write("\n")
                    f3.write("\n")
```

I tried to copy out of the container in the console with:

```
docker cp container_id:/container_workdir/only_premise_dataset_token_to_id_lemmatized.txt /destination
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip git build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev #libcupti-dev

WORKDIR /container_workdir

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=7
RUN export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=7

CMD bash
```

Note that I also tried re-storing the files as `.csv` and `.tsv` and also with `pickle` inside the container. None of these approaches worked either.

EDIT as @Minarth stated, I get an error:

```
Error: No such container:path: container_id:/container_workdir/only_premise_dataset_token_to_id_lemmatized.txt
```

Comment: did yop get any error after running `docker cp`?

Comment: Yes, the error was `Error: No such container:path: container_id:/container_workdir/only_premise_dataset_token_to_id_lemmatized.txt`.